# Clarity datagrid nested component broken after upgrade to 1.0.2

Tags: vmware-clarity, clarity

Since there is no clarity tree table, Developed tree table control which looks like clarity Datagrid. I used Datagrid and tweaked around(created a custom component which wraps rows and nested rows) after a couple of CSS override it was successful.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/clarity-light-theme-v013-wsiu1d

after upgrading to 1.0.2 it seems to be not working https://stackblitz.com/edit/clarity-light-theme-v013-zbetpr

Got to know that it's broken after 1.0.0 release due to new rendering changes made in clarity datagrid.
https://github.com/vmware/clarity/issues/2875

Is there a possibility this feature will be back or any possible workaround to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In actually only partially worked before the 1.0 rendering refactoring, certain features would not have worked properly using this technique. It is also not supported. The problem with your original (and somewhat functional) example is that you're breaking the Datagrid model by having multiple rows inside of one another. If you try to add selection, it breaks in your scenario.

Why not consider the [Tree View component](https://clarity.design/documentation/tree-view) for displaying hierarchical structures? If fits your data model and intention from what I can see in your demo.

Comment: Hi Jeremy, thanks for your response, Yes you are right some of the functions like sort, filter and selection would not work out of the box in this case. but I just needed a tabular hierarchical control so I took this approach, in fact, it did work very well for all the requirement I had, little sad all the effort of customizing datagrid to tree table is going to waste. Since i needed a tabular hierarchical structure, didn't consider TreeView component. I need a header, rows, columns and cells.

Comment: Well you want something that we don't currently support then, a hybrid TreeView and Datagrid. You can see the details of why here: https://github.com/vmware/clarity/issues/2759